# Redirect URL on CheckBox Click event without page reload

Tags: jquery, ajax

Here is My Checkbox code. Checkbox value get: `http://mydomainsss.com/men.html?band_colour=131`

```
<span class="check-box">
    <input type="checkbox" name="vehicle" class="filtercheckbox" value="<?php echo $this->urlEscape($_item->getUrl())?>" />
</span>
```

Here is my Jquery Code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
jQuery('input[type=checkbox').click(function(){

      window.location.hash = jQuery(this).val();
    });
</script>
```

This code simple change `URL` like  `http://mydomainsss.com/men.html#http://mydomainsss.com.com/men.html?band_colour=131`

but I want to `redirect` to `http://mydomainsss.com/men.html?band_colour=131`
without page `reload`.
so can anyone help me?

Comment: Where did you assign check box value?

Comment: use window.history.pushState like @vinhphon answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/47827300/2076049

Answer (score 0):

Just use hash in the value of the input, not whole URL.

```js
jQuery('input[type=checkbox').change(function(){
  window.location.hash = jQuery(this).val();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<span class="check-box">
  <input type="checkbox" name="vehicle" class="filtercheckbox" value="#something" />
</span>
```

Comment: but in the checkbox value i only get values like "131" thats why i need to use whole URL.

Answer (score 0):

Just use ways below instead of use .hash

```
window.location.replace(jQuery(this).val());

or
window.location.href = jQuery(this).val();

or Jquery
$(location).attr('href', jQuery(this).val())
```

### This way will redirect to new link.

UPDATE: 
I used to think you want to REDIRECT this page.

If you just want to change the url, please research html5 function

history.pushState

---

If you want to redirect without pageload, you have to research Angular, React, Backbone...

Or use ajax page load libarry such as: pjax, smoothState.js to load some content without page reload.

---

Thanks for unvote :(

Answer (score -1):

Change `window.location.hash` to `window.location.href`:

```html
<script type="text/javascript">
  jQuery('input[type=checkbox').click(function(){
    window.location.href = jQuery(this).val();
  });
</script>
```

Comment: i want to change without page reload

Comment: How are you supposed to redirect w/o reload. You can only set some hash w/o reload ;)